# Enumeration of the roots of a polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

In `Root[f,k]`, how exactly are the roots of a polynomial `f` enumerated?

The Mathematica manual seems to only say that

> The ordering used by Root[f,k] takes real roots to come before complex
>   ones, and takes complex conjugate pairs of roots to be adjacent.

Of course, in general this does not completely determine the ordering/enumeration of the roots.

Comment: Example of a real numeric root listed $\it{after}$ the numeric complex roots with MMA 12.0.  `Clear[a, b, c] ; Table[  FullSimplify[ ToRadicals@ Root[ (# - a)  (# - b)  (# - c)  (#^5 + 32) &, k ], {a, b, c}  \[Element]  Reals],  {k, 1, 8} ]`  Real symbolic roots also come last.

Comment: Strange example with only 3 complex roots (!) and they are sorted out of canonical order in MMA 12.0;   `Clear[a, b, c]; Table[ ToRadicals @ FullSimplify[ Root[ (# - a)  (# - b)  (# - c)  (#^5 + 32) &, k ], {a, b, c}  \[Element]  Reals],  {k, 1, 8} ]`

Comment: @LouisB - The canonical ordering is done on the raw form, i.e., before you use the functions `ToRadicals` and `FullSimplify`. Similarly, `Sort` does not use `N` to sort numeric expressions unless you explicitly use `SortBy[expr, N]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sol = Solve[x^5 + x^3 + 1 == 0, x]
```

[image]

The roots are sorted in canonical order as verified by [`OrderedQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderedQ.html)

```
OrderedQ@sol

(* True *)
```

The real roots are first, then the complex roots are sorted first by real part and then by imaginary part.

```
sol2 = Solve[x^5 + a x^3 + b == 0, x];
```

Again, the roots are sorted in canonical order

```
OrderedQ@sol2

(* True *)
```

Mathematica's canonical order is described in the documentation for [`Sort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish people like you wrote the manual.